# Alternative to using VMs to simulate virtual network in windows

Tags: windows

I am running two instances of a program separately on two VMware Workstation VMs using NAT. Is there a way i can do the same without using VMs, since they consume a lot of system resources.

Comment: its probably a good idea to identify WHY the program can only run one instance per system. that is almost never a choice an application designer would make unless there is an architectural reason it must be that way, and that reason (whatever it may be) will shape the possible answers to your question. we can't help you much more than that, especially if we don't even know the name of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way i can do the same without using VMs

Generally not. VMs are the only truly full featured virtual machines on a single host.

Make sure you have a decent host and as fast SSD main disk. I have 3 VMs running at all times and they are quite fast and low resource.

The only other approach is WSL, but that is not a VM, not fully featured and generally not flexible enough to run numerous programs. WSL does not have the flexible networking that true VMs have.

Dual boot is an approach, but (a) that means slow changing system to get to the other system and (b) some complexity setting it up. I don't think this meets your goal of "doing this without VMs". I personally do not recommend this.

A good fast machine will let VMs work effectively.